# how to generate two .so file in a single android.mk file

Tags: android, makefile, java-native-interface, gnu-make

I'd like to create two .so file within a single .mk file. But the following codes fails because there should not be a space in LOCAL_MODULE. So is there a way out?

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := gpio hello-jni
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror    
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := gpio.c hello-jni.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just got it works using the following codes.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := gpio 
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror    
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := gpio.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := h ello-jni
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```